# How do i invoke a method in c#?

Tags: c#

I need to invoke a method to then print it, right now i get .NaN as the output when you enter the right temperature.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace Bastun2
{
    class Pogram
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double temperatureF = double.NaN;
            double temperatureC = double.NaN;
            string input = string.Empty;
            bool inputIsOkay = false;


            while (!inputIsOkay) //Tells you to repeat until input is true
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter temperature in numbers."); //Asks for temperature

                input = Console.ReadLine(); //Input temperature

                if (!double.TryParse(input, out temperatureF)) //Prevents you for using letters
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"'{input}' is not a valid input. Use numbers and , not ."); //Tells you not to use letter or "."
                }
                else if (temperatureF < 163.4)//Repeat if temperature is under 163.4
                {
                    //temperatureC = (temperatureF - 32) * 5 / 9; //Converts Farneheight to Celcius
                    Console.WriteLine($"Temperature is to low, enter a higher temperature.");  //Tells you that temperature is to low and asks you to input a higher temperature
                }
                else if (temperatureF > 170.6)//Repeat if temperature is to high
                {
                    //temperatureC = (temperatureF - 32) * 5 / 9; //Converts Farneheight to Celcius
                    Console.WriteLine($"Temperature is to high, enter a lower temperature.");//Tells you that temperature is to high and asks you to input a lower temperature
                }
                else
                {
                    inputIsOkay = true; //kick you out of the loop if input is true
                }
            }



            //temperatureC = (temperatureF - 32) * 5 / 9; //Converts Farneheight to Celcius
            //Console.ReadLine(calculateC);
            Console.WriteLine($"{temperatureC}°C, temperature is within acceptable parameters");//prints C and tell you that temperature is acceptable
        }
        public static double CToF(double temperatureF, double temperatureC)
        {
            temperatureC = (temperatureF - 32) * 5 / 9;
            return temperatureC;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're invoking all sorts of methods in the code you posted. What do you mean?

Comment: I want o invoke CToF in the Console.Writeline so that i can get a value for temperatureC in the writeline. Maybe im a bit confused about wht is what, im quite new at this

Comment: Yes, you are. `Console.WriteLine(...)` is invoking a method.

Comment: oooh, didn't know that counted as a method, have changed my first responce, how do i invoke CToF in the console writeline?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(CToF(tempF, tempC));` Your CToF() method really should only have the first parameter though. It doesn't need the C value to do the calculation. It just returns it.

Comment: it still posts .NaN

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your replies to the original, I can see an obvious problem from the get go. You're never setting the value for the temperatureC variable which is why you're always getting NaN as you're output when you're trying to print it.

You're already invoking a lot of methods by calling them such as `Console.WriteLine(...)`, etc.

All you need to do is this at the bottom of the Main method under the `while` loop:

```cs
temperatureC = CToF(temperatureF, temperatureC);
```

And then output the value of `temperatureC` like you are doing with:

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"{temperatureC}°C, temperature is within acceptable parameters");
```

Another small suggestion to make your code a little more efficient as well as readable is to change your CToF method and just do this:

```cs
        public static double CToF(double temperatureF)
        {
            return (temperatureF - 32) * 5 / 9;
        }
```

If you decide to accept that idea of improvement, you can then just invoke the method like so:

```cs
temperatureC = CToF(temperatureF);
```